# Springbatch hits EmptyResultDataAccessException when using partition step

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-transactions, isolation-level

I have been stuck an EmptyResultDataAccessException for weeks in my spring batch partition step. After some investigation, the exception throw from the SQL of

```
    SELECT VERSION FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=?
```

right after some partition handlers start, most of the partition handlers success. This exception appear randomly. I suspected it was due to the mysql default transaction isolation was REPEADABLE_READ, so it was a symptom of phantom read. Then I changed to READ_COMMITTED. The symptom did not happen again. However, I have no way to provide my finding was real root cause and my change can really fix the problem.

It makes me more confuse is why this case seems not been reported. I googled a lot but invalid. So I try to find out the root cause. Here are log messages about jdbc and transaction for a case I reproduced

```
2019-09-02 10:44:40,342 [myTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG AbstractStep                   - Executing: id=8281
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,342 [myTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG JpaTransactionManager          - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,342 [myTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG JpaTransactionManager          - Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@38839485] for JPA transaction
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,343 [myTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG AbstractStep                   - Executing: id=8280
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,343 [myTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG JpaTransactionManager          - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@3988f55b]
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,343 [myTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG JpaTransactionManager          - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,343 [myTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG JpaTransactionManager          - Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@7f95ee7e] for JPA transaction
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,343 [myTaskExecutor-2] TRACE nsactionSynchronizationManager - Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@39d2dbed] for key [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@791f2f3c{ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null; defaultReadOnly=null; defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; defaultCatalog=null; driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver; maxActive=20; maxIdle=20; minIdle=10; initialSize=10; maxWait=1000; testOnBorrow=true; testOnReturn=false; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; testWhileIdle=false; testOnConnect=false; password=********; url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.200.231:3306/hut_ptms_cp?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8; username=ptms_web; validationQuery=SELECT 1; validationQueryTimeout=-1; validatorClassName=null; validationInterval=3000; accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true; removeAbandoned=false; removeAbandonedTimeout=60; logAbandoned=false; connectionProperties=null; initSQL=null; jdbcInter...
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,343 [myTaskExecutor-2] TRACE nsactionSynchronizationManager - Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@39d2dbed] for key [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@791f2f3c{ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null; defaultReadOnly=null; defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; defaultCatalog=null; driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver; maxActive=20; maxIdle=20; minIdle=10; initialSize=10; maxWait=1000; testOnBorrow=true; testOnReturn=false; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; testWhileIdle=false; testOnConnect=false; password=********; url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.200.231:3306/hut_ptms_cp?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8; username=ptms_web; validationQuery=SELECT 1; validationQueryTimeout=-1; validatorClassName=null; validationInterval=3000; accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true; removeAbandoned=false; removeAbandonedTimeout=60; logAbandoned=false; connectionProperties=null; initSQL=null; jdbcInter...
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,343 [myTaskExecutor-2] TRACE nsactionSynchronizationManager - Bound value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@36306823] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@5aa72974] to thread [myTaskExecutor-2]
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,343 [myTaskExecutor-2] TRACE nsactionSynchronizationManager - Bound value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@36306823] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@5aa72974] to thread [myTaskExecutor-2]
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,343 [myTaskExecutor-2] TRACE nsactionSynchronizationManager - Initializing transaction synchronization
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,343 [myTaskExecutor-2] TRACE TransactionInterceptor         - Getting transaction for [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update]
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,343 [myTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG JdbcTemplate                   - Executing prepared SQL update
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,343 [myTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG JdbcTemplate                   - Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION set START_TIME = ?, END_TIME = ?, STATUS = ?, COMMIT_COUNT = ?, READ_COUNT = ?, FILTER_COUNT = ?, WRITE_COUNT = ?, EXIT_CODE = ?, EXIT_MESSAGE = ?, VERSION = ?, READ_SKIP_COUNT = ?, PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT = ?, WRITE_SKIP_COUNT = ?, ROLLBACK_COUNT = ?, LAST_UPDATED = ? where STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ? and VERSION = ?]
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,346 [myTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG JdbcTemplate                   - SQL update affected 1 rows
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,347 [myTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG JdbcTemplate                   - Executing prepared SQL query
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,347 [myTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG JdbcTemplate                   - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT VERSION FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=?]
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,348 [myTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG JpaTransactionManager          - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@58f60cd]
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,348 [myTaskExecutor-1] TRACE nsactionSynchronizationManager - Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@12cbfc0e] for key [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@791f2f3c{ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null; defaultReadOnly=null; defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; defaultCatalog=null; driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver; maxActive=20; maxIdle=20; minIdle=10; initialSize=10; maxWait=1000; testOnBorrow=true; testOnReturn=false; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; testWhileIdle=false; testOnConnect=false; password=********; url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.200.231:3306/hut_ptms_cp?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8; username=ptms_web; validationQuery=SELECT 1; validationQueryTimeout=-1; validatorClassName=null; validationInterval=3000; accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true; removeAbandoned=false; removeAbandonedTimeout=60; logAbandoned=false; connectionProperties=null; initSQL=null; jdbcInter...
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,348 [myTaskExecutor-1] TRACE nsactionSynchronizationManager - Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@12cbfc0e] for key [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@791f2f3c{ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null; defaultReadOnly=null; defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; defaultCatalog=null; driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver; maxActive=20; maxIdle=20; minIdle=10; initialSize=10; maxWait=1000; testOnBorrow=true; testOnReturn=false; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; testWhileIdle=false; testOnConnect=false; password=********; url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.200.231:3306/hut_ptms_cp?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8; username=ptms_web; validationQuery=SELECT 1; validationQueryTimeout=-1; validatorClassName=null; validationInterval=3000; accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true; removeAbandoned=false; removeAbandonedTimeout=60; logAbandoned=false; connectionProperties=null; initSQL=null; jdbcInter...
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,348 [myTaskExecutor-1] TRACE nsactionSynchronizationManager - Bound value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@42fd1637] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@5aa72974] to thread [myTaskExecutor-1]
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,348 [myTaskExecutor-1] TRACE nsactionSynchronizationManager - Bound value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@42fd1637] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@5aa72974] to thread [myTaskExecutor-1]
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,348 [myTaskExecutor-1] TRACE nsactionSynchronizationManager - Initializing transaction synchronization
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,348 [myTaskExecutor-1] TRACE TransactionInterceptor         - Getting transaction for [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update]
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,348 [myTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG JdbcTemplate                   - Executing prepared SQL update
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,350 [myTaskExecutor-2] TRACE TransactionInterceptor         - Completing transaction for [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update]
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,348 [myTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG JdbcTemplate                   - Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION set START_TIME = ?, END_TIME = ?, STATUS = ?, COMMIT_COUNT = ?, READ_COUNT = ?, FILTER_COUNT = ?, WRITE_COUNT = ?, EXIT_CODE = ?, EXIT_MESSAGE = ?, VERSION = ?, READ_SKIP_COUNT = ?, PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT = ?, WRITE_SKIP_COUNT = ?, ROLLBACK_COUNT = ?, LAST_UPDATED = ? where STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ? and VERSION = ?]
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,350 [myTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG JpaTransactionManager          - Initiating transaction commit
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,352 [myTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG JpaTransactionManager          - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@38839485]
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,354 [myTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG JdbcTemplate                   - SQL update affected 1 rows
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,354 [myTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG JdbcTemplate                   - Executing prepared SQL query
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,354 [myTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG JdbcTemplate                   - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT VERSION FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=?]
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,356 [myTaskExecutor-1] TRACE TransactionInterceptor         - Completing transaction for [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update] after exception: org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,356 [myTaskExecutor-1] TRACE RuleBasedTransactionAttribute  - Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,356 [myTaskExecutor-1] TRACE RuleBasedTransactionAttribute  - Winning rollback rule is: null
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,356 [myTaskExecutor-1] TRACE RuleBasedTransactionAttribute  - No relevant rollback rule found: applying default rules
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,356 [myTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG JpaTransactionManager          - Initiating transaction rollback
 2019-09-02 10:44:40,356 [myTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG JpaTransactionManager          - Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@7f95ee7e]
```

The myTaskExecutor-1 was the problem thread. The myTaskExecutor-2 was a normal thread and it was do the same process with thread 1 and they were in the same partition. The case told me that the root cause was not time critical as thread 2's transaction began ahead of the thread 1.  And I could not found any different 2 threads from the log messages. Can somebody can help and give me some advise?

Mysql version: 5.7.18
SpringBatch version: 3.0.7

Comment: According to `The myTaskExecutor-2 was a normal thread and it was do the same process with thread 1 and they were in the same partition`, I guess you have two threads competing for the same partition. Are you sure there is no overlap in the definition of your partitions and that each thread is handling a different partition?

Comment: Yes, The threads printed the ids they received 

```
2019-09-02 10:44:40,342 [myTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG AbstractStep                   - Executing: id=8281
2019-09-02 10:44:40,343 [myTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG AbstractStep                   - Executing: id=8280
```

Comment: ok thanks. In that case, I also suspect the problem is due to the isolation level of your transaction. I would use READ_COMMITTED or better.

Comment: Yes, I have applied the READ_COMMITTED, however, I have no idea how I can provide it works.